# zlib and mingw32

Tags: mingw, zlib

When using zlib with mingw32, should I be linking to the `zlib1.dll` file, or to some `zlib.so` file? I would think the latter, but cannot find any resources explaining how to get and/or use such a file.

Comment: Really - [can't find it?](http://tinyurl.com/5wprf7q). Pick a random project page and read: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/zlib/

Comment: @sehe I went through nearly all the top 20 Google results. They all refer to using the `.dll`

Comment: soo, why do you think you should use the so? Are you not telling us vital information (are you on linux?)

Comment: @sehe No, I am on windows. I just thought that the "native" thing for mingw was `.so` libraries, and `.dll`'s must have some kind of wrapper which incurs an overhead.

Comment: The good news is: you were making things more complicated than necessary

Comment: @sehe "The good news is: you were making things more complicated than necessary" - How so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also on linux the usual recipe is

```
mingw-g++ ...... -lole32
```

which links to a DLL, **not** an .so; *The executable produced is also a Windows executable, remember.*

See e.g. my recent post here: [Discovering registered COM components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670548/discovering-registered-com-components/6671397#6671397) which compiles the same binary on both linux and windows